# Summation over set notation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, quantum-information

I am reading some lecture notes on quantum computing and ran into the following expression that I cannot seem to understand:

> For example, if we apply the Hadamard gate $H$ to each bit in a register of $n$ zeroes, we obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{j \in \{0,1\}^n} | j \rangle$, which is a superposition of all $n$-bit strings.
>   More generally, if we apply $H^{\otimes n}$ to an initial state $| i \rangle$, with $i \in \{0,1\}^n$, we obtain
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{2.1}
>     H^{\otimes n} | i \rangle
>   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}
>     \sum_{j \in \{0,1\}^n}
>     (-1)^{i \cdot j} | j \rangle,
> \end{equation}
>   where $i \cdot j = \sum_{k=1}^n i_k j_k$ denotes the inner product of the $n$-bit strings $i, j \in \{0, 1\}^n$.
>   For example:
>   $$
>     H^{\otimes 2} | 01 \rangle
>   =         \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( | 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle )
>     \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( | 0 \rangle - | 1 \rangle )
>   = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j \in \{0,1\}^2} (-1)^{01 \cdot j} | j \rangle.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqhHd.jpg).)

In both of the summations, a set is implied but I do not see how it would work if it were expanded. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{0,1\}^n$ denotes the set of all bit strings of length $n$.  So, for instance, with $n=3$ and $i = 011$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
H ^{\otimes 3}|i \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^3}} \sum_{j \in \{0,1\}^3} (-1)^{i \cdot j}
\\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^3}}\left[(-1)^{(000)\cdot i}|000 \rangle + (-1)^{(001) \cdot i}|001 \rangle  + \cdots + (-1)^{(111) \cdot i}|111 \rangle\right]
\\ & =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^3}}\left[|000 \rangle -|001 \rangle  -|010 \rangle + |011 \rangle + |100 \rangle - |101 \rangle - |110 \rangle + |111 \rangle\right]
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I guess that should've been clear by the preceding text but I glazed over it. It makes sense now. Now that I understand, is there a direct way to factor the expanded expression back to tensor notation?

Comment: There is no general method of factoring a sum back into a tensor product.  In general, this amounts to the problem of [Tensor rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition).  In the case of $n=2$, this factorization is easy to find because it is equivalent to computing a [(matrix) rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).

Answer (score 3):

The sum in (2.1) is over all length-$n$ vectors with each entry $0$ or $1$. The symbol $i$ is also such a vector, so the dot product $i\cdot j$ in $(-1)^{i\cdot j}$ is the sum of values of $k$ for which $i_k=j_k=1$. In the unnumbered display-line equation below, the same thing happens with the special case $n=2,\,i_1=0,\,i_2=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the inner product part but without viewing these as bit strings I was lost.